# 1-loop renormalization of scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

Let me consider scalar QED without the scalar self-interactions. Applying the prescription of renormalized perturbation theory to introduce renormalized quantities
\begin{equation}
\phi_0=\phi\sqrt{Z_0},\quad A_0=A\sqrt{Z_3},\quad e_0=eZ_e,\quad m_0=m \sqrt{Z_m},
\end{equation}
and expanding all the $Z$'s as $1+\delta$ as usual, I get the following Lagrangian

\begin{equation}
\mathcal L=\mathcal L_{free}+\mathcal L_{int} +\mathcal L_{c.t.}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\mathcal L_{free}=-\phi^*(\Box+m^2)\phi-1/4F^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal L_{int}=-ieA^\mu(\phi^*\partial_\mu\phi-\phi\partial_\mu\phi^*)+e^2A^2|\phi|^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal L_{c.t.}=-\phi^*(\delta_0\Box+(\delta_0+\delta_m)m^2)\phi-1/4\delta_3F^2-i(\delta_e+\delta_3/2+\delta_0)eA^\mu(\phi^*\partial_\mu\phi-\phi\partial_\mu\phi^*)+\\+(2\delta_e+\delta_3+\delta_0)e^2A^2|\phi|^2
\end{equation}

I can set the values of $\delta_0$, $\delta_m$, $\delta_3$, and $\delta_e$ removing the divergencies in the scalar field propagator, the photon field propagator, and in the $\phi\phi\gamma$ interaction.

However, there is another class of naively divergent diagrams, namely those contributing to the $\phi\phi\gamma\gamma$ interaction.

**Question: How do I prove that the divergencies encountered in the 1-loop corrections to the $\phi\phi\gamma\gamma$ vertex can be eliminated by $(2\delta_e+\delta_3+\delta_0)$ ?**

Edit: I have begun listing the 1PI loop diagrams correcting the bare vertex (I found 5 of them). It may be that the divergences cancel out, but it can't be just a coincidence.

Comment: Not sure, but can you argue that since there's no need to cancel it in Dirac's gauge $A^2=0$, it cancels automatically in any gauge?

Comment: @and008, Thank you for the interesting answer. However, setting $A^2=0$ does not prevent divergent loop corrections to the $\phi\phi\gamma\gamma$ vertex, or does it? 

My argument is that it does since we can show that the divergence is proportional to $g^{\mu\nu}$, i.e. $\text{div}\{<\phi\phi^*A^{\mu}A^{\nu}>\}\sim c g^{\mu\nu}$ with a possibly divergent $c$. Contracting both sides with $g_{\mu\nu}$ we get $c=0$ by Dirac's gauge.

Comment: Looks good. I had in mind using Dirac's gauge directly at the level of Lagrangian, ie. avoiding the trouble of the $\phi\phi\gamma\gamma$ vertices altogether. In any case, using the Ward-Takahashi identities to relate the divergencies is the safest bet.

Comment: However, I can't get the correct result with the direct calculation (see the linked question).