# Four point function renormalization in scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

I am computing the 4-point $\langle \phi\phi^* A^{\mu} A^{\nu}\rangle$ function in scalar QED* and I have found 5 1PI diagrams correcting the tree-level vertex $2ie^2g^{\mu\nu}$.
I would like to explicitly check that the counterterm generated by renormalized perturbation theory, i.e. $2ie^2(2\delta_1-\delta_0)g^{\mu\nu}$, with $\delta_1$ the 3-point function counterterm and $\delta_0$ the $p^2$ counterterm, cancels the divergences coming from these diagrams.

[image: 1PI contributions to the 4-point function]

In order to do so, the coefficient of the divergence should be $-\frac{ie^4}{4\pi^2} 2g^{\mu\nu}$. However, considering only the leading terms in the integrals, I have the following behaviours for the 5 diagrams
\begin{equation}
\small
-e^4\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{4k^2 k^\mu k^\nu}{(k^2-\Delta)^4},\quad -e^4\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{4k^4 g^{\mu\nu}}{(k^2-\Delta)^2},\quad e^4\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{2k^4 g^{\mu\nu}}{(k^2-\Delta)^2}, \quad e^4\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{4 k^2 k^\mu k^\nu}{(k^2-\Delta)^2},\quad e^4\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{4 k^2 k^\mu k^\nu }{(k^2-\Delta)^2},
\end{equation}
which add up to
\begin{equation}
-e^4\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{k^4g^{\mu\nu}}{(k^2-\Delta)^4}\overset{div}{=}-\frac{ie^4}{16\pi^2}\frac{2 g^{\mu\nu}}{\epsilon}.
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, this is $4$ times smaller than what I expected.

**Where am I wrong?**

*Without scalar self-interactions, cfr. [my previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629521/1-loop-renormalization-of-scalar-qed?noredirect=1#comment1415746_629521)

Comment: It's been 10 months since this question was posted but since I am now stuck on the same problem I wonder if OP has solved it and how

Comment: The solution lies in the different multiplicity of the diagrams, which is 2 for all but the third one (in which case it's one). The total contribution is thus proportional to -2-2*4+1*2+2+2=-4 instead of -1-4+2+1+1=-1.